# Что я делаю не так. Помогите

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import asyncio
import subprocess
from colorama import init, Fore
import time
import keyboard
import cv2
import sys

init()
print(f'{Fore.RED}██████╗░██╗░██████╗░█████╗░░█████╗░██████╗░██████╗░  ██████╗░░█████╗░████████╗')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██╔══██╗██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗  ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██║░░██║██║╚█████╗░██║░░╚═╝██║░░██║██████╔╝██║░░██║  ██████╦╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██║░░██║██║░╚═══██╗██║░░██╗██║░░██║██╔══██╗██║░░██║  ██╔══██╗██║░░██║░░░██║░░░')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██████╔╝██║██████╔╝╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░░██║██████╔╝  ██████╦╝╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'╚═════╝░╚═╝╚═════╝░░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░  ╚═════╝░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░')
time.sleep(0.1)
print()
time.sleep(0.1)
print()
time.sleep(0.1)
print()
print(f'░█████╗░██████╗░███████╗░█████╗░████████╗░█████╗░██████╗░  ██████╗░██╗░░░██╗████████╗██╗░░██╗░█████╗░███╗░░██╗')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗  ██╔══██╗╚██╗░██╔╝╚══██╔══╝██║░░██║██╔══██╗████╗░██║')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██║░░╚═╝██████╔╝█████╗░░███████║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██████╔╝  ██████╔╝░╚████╔╝░░░░██║░░░███████║██║░░██║██╔██╗██║')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██║░░╚═╝██████╔╝█████╗░░███████║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██████╔╝  ██████╔╝░╚████╔╝░░░░██║░░░███████║██║░░██║██╔██╗██║')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'██║░░╚═╝██████╔╝█████╗░░███████║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██████╔╝  ██████╔╝░╚████╔╝░░░░██║░░░███████║██║░░██║██╔██╗██║')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'╚█████╔╝██║░░██║███████╗██║░░██║░░░██║░░░╚█████╔╝██║░░██║  ██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░░░░██║░░░██║░░██║╚█████╔╝██║░╚███║')
time.sleep(0.1)
print(f'░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝  ╚═╝░░░░░░░░╚═╝░░░░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝{Fore.RESET}')
time.sleep(0.1)

print('█▄▄ █▄█   █▀█ ▄▀█ █░█ █▀▀ █░░ █▀ █▀ █▀ █▀█ █▀█')
print('█▄█ ░█░   █▀▀ █▀█ ▀▄▀ ██▄ █▄▄ ▄█ ▄█ ▄█ ▀▀█ █▄█')



create = input('Введите токен: ')
'''
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')
    # while True:
    game = discord.Game("/help и меня писал Павел")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=game)'''
with open('main.py', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(f'import discord\nfrom discord import utils\nfrom discord.utils import get\nfrom discord.ext import commands\n\nclient = commands.Bot( command_prefix = "!")\n\n\n@client.event\nasync def on_ready():\n\tprint("Бот запущен")\n\n\n\nclient.run("{create}")')
time.sleep(1)
p = subprocess.Popen('python3 main.py')
print('Нажмите ctrl+shift для завершения работы')
def callback():
    p.terminate()
    print('Забершена работа програмы')
    keyboard.remove_hotkey('ctrl+shift')
    maincode()


keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift', callback)
def maincode():
    ch = int(input('Что вы хотите сделать?\n(1)Запустить\n(2)Выйти '))
    print(ch)
    if ch == 1:
        p = subprocess.Popen('python3 main.py')
        print('Нажмите ctrl+shift для завершения работы')
        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift', callback)
    elif ch == 2:
        print('Досвидание. Буду рад видеть вас снова')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        maincode()
```

И мне в лицо прилетает ошибка

```
Что вы хотите сделать?
(1)Запустить
(2)Выйти Exception in thread Thread-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 58, in process
    if self.pre_process_event(event):
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 218, in pre_process_event
    callback(event)
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 649, in <lambda>
    handler = lambda e: (event_type == KEY_DOWN and e.event_type == KEY_UP and e.scan_code in _logically_pressed_keys) or (event_type == e.event_type and callback())
  File "C:/Users/b0tbo/Desktop/bot creator/app.py", line 64, in callback
    maincode()
  File "C:/Users/b0tbo/Desktop/bot creator/app.py", line 69, in maincode
    ch = int(input('Что вы хотите сделать?\n(1)Запустить\n(2)Выйти '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Я понимаю что она значит но никак не пойму как её решить

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так сделать:

```
input_data = input('Что вы хотите сделать?\n(1)Запустить\n(2)Выйти ')
if (input_data.isdigit()):
    command = int(input_data)
    if command == 1:
        pass
    elif command == 2:
        pass
```

Ошибка значит данные не являются числом.